Can the definition of particles in QFT as states that transform under irreducible unitary representations of the Poincare group be extended to solids?
I've been reading Matthew D. Schwartz's book on Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model and on page 110 he states the following:


Particles transform under irreducible unitary representations of the Poincare group.

This statement can even be interpreted as the definition of what a particle is.

I am aware that in condensed matter physics quasiparticles can be loosely defined as diagonal matrix representations of the terms in a Hamiltonian, i.e. terms expressible as
$$\mathcal{H}\propto\sum_p\epsilon\left(p\right)a^\dagger_p a_p.$$
My question is, whether the aforementioned definition can be extended to the definition of a quasiparticle, i.e. if a statement s.a.

Quasiparticles transform under some representation of the space group of a solid.

is true or whether a somewhat similar statement exists.

Why the whole Galilean group and not only the symmetry group of the solid (a lattice)? Furthermore: the relevant irrep of Galilean group are projective unitary, due to Bargmann’s superselection rule, not simply unitary.

@ValterMoretti I overlooked this. I edited my question with respect to your suggestion.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/838115/2451

@Qmechanic Thank you for referencing the related post! Unfortunately this post doesn't seem to be answered (or at least the one answer given misses the point).
